# Tablet Touch Screen partially unresponsive

Tags: touchscreen

I have an Android Tablet with Android 4.1.1, some days ago, the screen started to have random touches around the top of the screen, and sometimes, the top of the screen was unresponsive.
After a factory reset, the problem wasn't solved, but now the top of the screen had stopped being sensitive... I opened the tablet and cleaned the screen.
Now it stopped the random touches (Sometimes they happen again), but the screen still doesn't respond, what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a low tech answer but I've had this happen before, normally due to screen smudge from fingers or liquid splash/residue on the screen.

Give the screen a good clean (use cloth from a pair of glasses) and see if the problem persists.  Failing that, shutdown, remove the battery, and leave it for 5 minutes just in case it's a charge/capacitance issue.

Comment: (S)he said they tried cleaning and opening the tablet already.

Comment: I tried opening it and cleaning it again with paper, before seeing you answer, and it worked for some seconds, and started going crazy again.  
But I think it really might solve the problem.  
Well, but now I need to fix the sound too, the speaker wire broke. ç. ç

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. Physically squeezing or lightly tapping the back (not the screen) of the problem area is a good temporary fix if you still have to use the device everyday. Still searching for a permanent fix in my case because most I've tried aren't working.